# JTable prevent Strings

Tags: java, numbers, jtable

How can I prevent strings in a JTable and allow and show only numbers?

like for example I press "a" on my keyboard I won't not even that "a" will be displayed in the JTable cell. literally nothing should happen unless a user types in a number. so how can I prevent even not showing "a" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time ago and solved by validating with an KeyListener. This is a dirty way of doing it, but it works. The only weakness is if you're trying to edit a lot of cells quickly if you're a fast writer. Anyhow, here's the code that worked for me. I've added some commentary, but in short; we're overriding the normal validation and check with a TextField KeyListener if the given key is the one we allow in the TextField. If we allow the key, we enable TextField editing, if not, we turn it off to prevent the character being printed in the TextField. I hope this helps you.

UPDATE 1:
adding a celleditor on the TestField to prevent premature data insertion.

```
public class TableValidation extends JFrame
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TableValidation x = new TableValidation();
    x.setVisible(true);
}

JPanel topPanel;
JTable table = new JTable();
JScrollPane scrollPane;
String[] columnNames;
String[][] dataValues;

public TableValidation()
{
    this.setTitle("JTable Cell Validation");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(300,112);

    // make our panel to tin the table to
    topPanel    = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.getContentPane().add(topPanel);

    // set some initial data for the table
    columnNames = new String[] {"Anything" ,"Numbers only"};
    dataValues  = new String[][] { {"h4x0r","1337"} };


    table.setRowHeight(50);
    table.setModel( new CustomTableModel(dataValues, columnNames) );

    TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1); // apply our validation to the 2nd column
    JTextField textfield = new JTextField(); // the textbox to which we test our validation

    // setup our validation system. were passing the textfield as out celleditor source
    tableColumn.setCellEditor(new MyCellEditor(textfield));
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textfield.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // check what keys can pass our test
            if (textfield.isFocusOwner())
            if (e.getKeyChar() != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) // we allow backspace, obviously
            if (!Character.isDigit(e.getKeyChar())) // if key is not a digit.. cancel editing
            {
                // when it detects an invalid input, set editable to false. this prevents the input to register
                textfield.setEditable(false);
                textfield.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                return;
            }
            textfield.setEditable(true);
        }
    });
}
}
class MyCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField textField;

public MyCellEditor(JTextField textField)
{
    this.textField=textField;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) 
{
    if (super.isCellEditable(e)) {
        if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent me = (MouseEvent) e;
            return me.getClickCount() >= 2;
        }
        if (e instanceof KeyEvent) {
            KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent) e;
            return ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F2;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() 
{
    return this.textField.getText();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) 
{
    this.textField.setFont(table.getFont());
    this.textField.setText(value.toString());
    return this.textField;
}
}
class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
CustomTableModel(String[][] data,String[] names)
{
    super(data, names);
}

// we always pass true in our tablemodel so we can validate somewhere else
public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int cols)
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Thank You that works but unfortunately it need to support fast typing so do you got any other example with custom cell editor ?

Comment: I know what the bug is, and I think fixed it. The textfield allowed for editting if the cell was focussed, even though the TextField was not directly clicked.  The TextField now has a check to see if the field has been double-clicked. If so, we can edit it. This should prevent fast typers inserting data in cells where it doesn't belong.

Comment: thanks for your effort but I solved my problem with a document filter and custom cell editor :) will edit my question soon for other people